# Why don't files send through ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, file

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (contact) {
        console.log("done successfully");
    },
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  name="f_name" type="text" />
    <input type="file" name="attached_file" />
</form>
```

And here is the result of `upload.php`:

```
if ( !empty($_FILES['attached_file']['size']) ){ }   // false
if ( !empty($_POST['f_name']) ){ }                   // true
```

Which means the value of input *(text type)* has been sent but the file hasn't. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Need to use `new FormData()`

Comment: @Pedram And how can I send it?

Comment: @u_mulder it would be great if you reopen my question and let receiving an answer which is containing some code example using `FormData()`.

Comment: Don't worry, There are some answers with `FormData()` Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571821/4540183) or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981045)

Comment: @Pedram thank you, but the link you provided throws this error for me *(when I implement that example)* `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: You should try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bzs4ryeq/) did you get error exactly in this way?

Comment: @Pedram I did it and all fine, thank you. Where are you from? Iran?

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help you. originally yes, and you?

Comment: @Pedram Me too .. And you live in Turkey, good :-)

Comment: Yes, kinda nice to meet you :)

Comment: In case you don't understand, duplicate question has already enough info for solving your problem.